# Parsing Incoming Data from Email Server Objective-C/IOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, parsing

i have data that i fetch from an email server i want to eliminate noise and parse date and subject of incoming data and output it to users in a textview

how should we fetch data from an email server?

incoming data is like

```
something....
something...
* OK [PERMANENTFLAGS ($Submitted $XAOL-SENT \Answered \Deleted \Draft \Flagged \Seen $Forwarded $MDNSent Forwarded XAOL-GOOD XAOL-GOODCHECK-DONE)] Permanent flags
. OK [READ-WRITE] SELECT completed
. fetch 1:* (body[header.fields (from subject date)])
* 1 FETCH (BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (FROM SUBJECT DATE)] {149}
Date: Mon, 07 Nov 2011 17:00:25 -0500 (EST)
From: "AOLWelcomeInfo" <AOLWelcomeInfo@message.aol.com>
Subject: Welcome to Your New Email Account!

)
. OK FETCH completed
```

i use this code to parse it

```
NSMutableData* data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    unsigned char c;
    for (;;) {
        recv(socket_, &c, sizeof(c), 0);
        if (c == '\n') {
            NSString* s = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data
                                                encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];

            NSRange range = [s rangeOfString:@"FETCH "];
            if( range.location != NSNotFound ) {


            NSMutableArray *substrings = [NSMutableArray new];
                NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:s];
                [scanner scanUpToString:@"}" intoString:nil];
                while(![scanner isAtEnd]) {
                    NSString *substring = nil;
                    [scanner scanString:@"}" intoString:nil];
                    if([scanner scanUpToString:@"*" intoString:&substring]) {
                        // If the space immediately followed the }, this will be skipped
                        [substrings addObject:substring];
                    }
                    [scanner scanUpToString:@")" intoString:nil]; // Scan all characters before next }
                }
                NSString *email;
                [emailList addObject:@"Select an Email"];
                for(int i=0; i<substrings.count;i++){
                    email = [substrings objectAtIndex:i];
                    [emailList addObject:email]; // add emails in emailList
                }

                NSLog(@"%@",emailList);
                [substrings release];
            }
```

My output from NSlog is like

```
"Select an email"
"Select an email"
```

when i debug it it enters if statement but i couldn't figure out why it doesnt parse it correctly.

it should be like :

```
"Select an email"
Date: Mon, 07 Nov 2011 17:00:25 -0500 (EST)
    From: "AOLWelcomeInfo" <AOLWelcomeInfo@message.aol.com>
    Subject: Welcome to Your New Email Account!)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was i was reading data by one line each time in `for(;;){}`  so every time when NSString S gets one line without parsing it i was deleting everything inside i changed whole parsing method to

[NSMutable array to UITableview when button clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8116263/nsmutable-array-to-uitableview-when-button-clicked)